# How to pick a string from a jtextfield , insert single quotes ' ', and then use it in a mysql syntax

Tags: java, mysql

I'm picking a string from a jtextfield, say, C001 and then use it in a java code within a 'WHERE' clause in mysql table. How do I insert the single quote marks to make it 'C001' to use it in sql as shown below.

```
String str;// which is (C001)
String sql= ("SELECT * FROM expenditure WHERE Expenditure = \"" +str+"\" ");
```

the way I've used it here it doesn't have the '  ', quotes that must be there. Other wise I get thi error:

```
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'C001' not found.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
```

Comment: *How do I insert the single quote marks to make it 'C001' to use it in sql as shown below.*. You don't. Ever. You use a prepared statement and pass the string as parameter instead. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet for bothering to extend your kindness to answer the question. I'm not an expert programmer, kindly show me example how to use a prepared statement and pass the string as parameter.

Comment: I have already. You just need to click on the link and read.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, have tried to work around it but not succeeded, The way I've finally worked it is to remove the Character combination with numbers. This works fine.

Comment: PreparedStatement is a must: security (SQL injection) and escape sequences (typing an apostrophe or backslash or ...). On the SQL side: single apostrophes are for string values, double quotes for column _names_, especially useful if the column name is a reserved keyword or contains a space or such.